# Pandas locate and apply changes to column

Tags: pandas, pandas-apply

This is something I always struggle with and is very beginner. Essentially, I want to locate and apply changes to a column based on a filter from another column.

Example input.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
data = [
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [1, 1],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)
# NOTE: In practice, I will be applying a more complex function
df['col2'] = df.loc[df['col1'] == 1, 'col2'].apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

**Returned output:**

```
   col1  col2
0     1   2.0
1     1   2.0
2     2   NaN
3     1   2.0
```

**Expected output:**

```
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     2
2     2     2
3     1     2
```

**What's happening:**

Records that do not meet the filtering condition are being set to null because of my apply / lambda routine

**What I request:**

The correct locate/filter and apply approach. I can achieve the expected frame using update, however I want to use locate and apply.

Comment: try df.loc[df['col1' ] == 1, 'col2']

Comment: (Btw, your tables were actually fine; you just needed to add a newline before the top of them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/71621042/2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `df['col2'] = ...`, you're setting *all* the values of `col2`. But, since you're only calling `apply` on *some* of the values, the values that aren't included get set to NaN. To fix that, save your mask and reuse it:

```
mask = df['col1'] == 1
df.loc[mask, 'col2'] = df.loc[mask, 'col2'].apply(lambda x: x+1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     2
1     1     2
2     2     1
3     1     2
```